# How to automatically save a source URL when saving an image in Firefox under Windows?

Tags: windows, firefox, images, metadata

How could I automatically record the original URL of an image when saving an image from a webpage in Firefox under Windows? The URL could be written, for example, as metadata in the image EXIF.

How could this be done for other file types (not only images)?

Under the Mac OS X this is solved very nicely by writing the source info into the file metadata; under Linux, to extended attributes.

Comment: Related: https://cweiske.de/tagebuch/exif-url.htm

Answer (score 0):

You could add the information in the `Details` tab of the file properties, Right click the file > Properties > Details tab. You could put the url in the Comments

I know that at least Images and MS Office documents have this. Unfortunately This will have limited use to you as Adobe, Notepad and html files don't have this, I'm assuming more don't as well.

[image: Details Tab]

Comment: This is, unfortunately, not an _automatic_ method, which I'm trying to find. Changing file properties manually is too time-consuming for my task.

Answer (score 0):

One (partial) solution is provided by the FF add-on ["Save Image in Folder"](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/save-image-in-folder/). It can't write the source URL into the image metadata, but allows including the domain name as part of its file name. This is not bad already.

The Safari extension which places the original URL of a downloaded file into the Finder Comments area of that file is called [DownloadComment](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/15833/downloadcomment)